# Whats wrong with this LINQ query (joins)

Tags: linq

Vendors   Vendorsid PointTo

```
      123   456 
      456   412 
      789   853
```

Items   StandardItemNumber  VendorSID    SerialNumber

```
    1234    123 A1234
    4567    123 A4567
    8523    456 A8523
    1234    456 A1234
```

From the procedure, I get 123 and point to as 456. I want to check if items from 123 are already there under vendor 456. So dupes should give me item 1234 since its present with vendor 456 with same Serial number.
But dupes is not getting executed at all. It hangs at that statement.

```
var vendors = db.hp_GetEligibleVendors();
var items = from i in db.Items 
            where i.VendorID.Equals(vendors.VendorID)
            select i;

foreach(var vendor in vendors)
{   
    var items = from i in db.Items 
                where i.VendorSID.Equals(vendor.VendorSID)
                select i;

    var dupes = from oi in items join di in db.Items
                on new 
                   { 
                       oi.ItemNumber,
                       oi.SerialNumber
                   }
                equals new 
                   { 
                       ItemNumber = di.ItemNumber,
                       SerialNumber = di.SerialNumber
                   }
                where di.VendorSID.Equals(vendor.PointToVendorSID)
                select oi;
}
```

In the above query, it takes forever to get dupes. What is wrong with this query?

Comment: Show us your datasource, your current output and your desired output.

Comment: You're creating one anonymous type containing `ItemNumber` and another containing `StandardItemNumber` so they'll never be equal.

Comment: Corrected to ItamNumber but still it's not resulting any output.

Comment: what defines a duplicate item?

Comment: Same number and serial number

Comment: _But dupes is not getting executed_. No, you only define it. You don't show any code that executes it. Where is it executed?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. I had to add ItemNumber = oi.ItemNumber,SerialNumber = oi.SerialNumber. That solved the proble. Thanks to all who replied.